# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray) - Already have converted the data to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

Trying to train a single layer NN for text based multi label classification problem.

```
model= Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=400, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, verbose=0, epochs=100)
```

Getting error as :

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

x_train is a 300-dim word2vec vectorized text data, each instance padded to 400 length. Contains 462 records.

Observations on training data are as below :

```
print('#### Shape of input numpy array #####')
print(x_train.shape)
print('#### Shape of each element in the array #####')
print(x_train[0].shape)
print('#### Object type for input data #####')
print(type(x_train))
print('##### Object type for first element of input data ####')
print(type(x_train[0]))

#### Shape of input numpy array #####
(462,)
#### Shape of each element in the array #####
(400, 300)
#### Object type for input data #####
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
##### Object type for first element of input data ####
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: I bet the `dtype` of `x_train` is `object`.  Often is this results from making an array from a list of arrays that vary in shape.  You show the shape of the first element.  But is that the shape of all 462?  What does `np.stack(x_train)` do?

Comment: `print(type(x))` usually isn't very useful.  `print(x.dtype)` is more informative.  If `dtype` is `object`, then it contains objects, such as other arrays.  If `float` it is a numeric array, and probably something `tensorflow` can use.

Comment: @hpaulj Yess the dtype was object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three problems

---

problem1
**This is your main problem, which directly caused the error**.
something's wrong with how you initialize/convert your x_train (and I think it is a bug, or you used some unusual way to construct your data), now your x_train is in fact an array of array, instead of a multi-dimensional array. So TensorFlow "thought" you have a 1D array according to its shape, which is not what you want.
the solution is to reconstruct the array before sending to fit():

```
x_train = np.array([np.array(val) for val in x_train])
```

---

problem2
Dense layer expects your input to have shape (batch_size, ..., input_dim), which means your last dimension of x_train must equal to input_dim, but you have 300, which is different from 400.
According to your description, your input dimension, which is the word vector dimension is 300, so you should change input_dim to 300:

```
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=300, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
```

or equivalently, directly provide input_shape instead

```
model.add(Dense(20, input_shape=(400, 300), kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
```

---

problem3
because dense, aka linear layer, is meant for "linear" input, so it expects each of its data to be a vector of one dimensional, so input is usually like (batch_size, vector_length). When dense receive an input of dimension > 2 (you got 3 dimensions), it will perform Dense operation on the last dimension. quote from TensorFlow official documentation:

> Note: If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then
> `Dense`   computes the dot product between the `inputs` and the
> `kernel` along the   last axis of the `inputs` and axis 1 of the
> `kernel` (using `tf.tensordot`).
> For example, if input has dimensions `(batch_size, d0, d1)`,   then we
> create a `kernel` with shape `(d1, units)`, and the `kernel` operates
> along axis 2 of the `input`, on every sub-tensor of shape `(1, 1, d1)`
> (there are `batch_size * d0` such sub-tensors).   The output in this
> case will have shape `(batch_size, d0, units)`.

This means your y should have shape (462, 400, 9) instead. which is most likely not what you are looking for (if this is indeed what you are looking for, code in problem1&2 should have solved your problem).

if you are looking for performing dense on the whole 400x300 matrix, you need to first flatten to a one-dimensional vector, like this:

```
x_train = np.array([np.array(val) for val in x_train])  # reconstruct
model= Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(400, 300)))
model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, verbose=0, epochs=100)
```

now the output will be (462, 9)